# Open terminal to execute command and then terminate if successful

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, shell

I want to open a terminal and have it accept to execute one command and then terminate (so that the terminal closes). Optionally, this should only happen if the previous command was successful to account for typos, forgetting `sudo` etc.

I have been attempting different solutions around piping `read line` to bash/sh, etc. but with little success. Some attempts:

```
exec foot sh -c "output=$(read line); sh -c $output
```

```
exec foot sh -c "read line | sh"
```

etc.

Comment: Would you be able to give some more background information please? Eg what do you mean "open a terminal"? Do you mean that for example users ssh in, or open a terminal emulator in your desktop session, or is this part of another script that runs? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assume `foot` is your terminal emulator and it accepts command as-is as arguments.

In `urxvt` the invocation sequence would be `urxvt -e command args...`.

First problem you have that is not how `read` shell builtin works!

Second read up `dash(1)` manual page about `read` builtin (I hope you are using dash, if you are aiming for proper `sh`, `bash` is unreliable to be used as `sh`, it simply cannot follow POSIX standard emulation).

Third, you need to read-in the line to execute, and then to replace the `foot` invoked shell with your command/line. So I would do something like this:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh
exec foot sh -c "IFS=\"\" read -p \"Type in a command:\" -r line_input ; exec \${line_input}"
```

Unfortunately shell is really bad "reader" or rather shell's `read` is really shitty general line editor.

Shell insists on always splitting the line read into multiple variables by $IFS characters, so `IFS=""` code tries to prevent that (there are corner cases when shell will split anyway because it's stupid).

Shell also insists on interpreting line embedded `\` characters, unless `-r` is also specified, thus we do that.

Even then, you will have problems with shell's stupid auto-splitting on arguments with spaces, typed directly into the `read` command input.

But I hope my snippet is sufficient for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to the `read` command these parameters :

Before the command : `IFS=` 
On the command : `-r -d $'\0')`

`IFS=` (with nothing after the equals sign) sets the internal
field separator to "no value". Spaces, tabs, and newlines are therefore
considered part of a word, thus preserving white space.

`-r` will preserve any backslashes in the entered value.

`-d` sets the newline delimiter, setting it to the
NULL character (ASCII code zero), in case the entered value
contains newlines.

Answer (score 0):

The question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash). This answer uses Bash.

`bash -t` exits after reading and executing one command, possibly complex command, one command "line" that may be quite a huge (and even multi-line) piece of shell code. `bash -t` exits regardless of the exit status of the command. To exit conditionally you need something more complex.

Create a file `~/.single_command_bashrc` and put the following code in it:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
   . /etc/bash.bashrc
fi

if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   . ~/.bashrc
fi

PS1="(transient) $PS1"
BASH_LATE_ENOUGH=
PROMPT_COMMAND='
[ "$?" -eq 0 ] && [ -n "$BASH_LATE_ENOUGH" ] && exit
BASH_LATE_ENOUGH=x
'
```

The file does not have to be executable.

Now if you run `bash --rcfile ~/.single_command_bashrc` then the newly opened interactive Bash will source `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` (like interactive Bash invoked without `--rcfile` would); but additionally it will configure itself to do what you want.

Inside this Bash the shell code stored in `PROMPT_COMMAND` will be executed every time a prompt is about to be printed. The code makes the shell exit just before it would otherwise print the prompt after a successful command. Because before the first prompt there's also a successful command, the helper variable named `BASH_LATE_ENOUGH` is used to make sure `exit` is not performed before the very first prompt. I could achieve a similar result just by adding `false` at the end of `~/.single_command_bashrc`, but if for any reason `set -e` would be active at the time, then this `false` would make the shell exit prematurely. IMO the variable is a better solution.

You need to tell your terminal emulator to run `bash --rcfile ~/.single_command_bashrc`. Judging *solely* by what you posted, I say the command may be:

```
foot bash --rcfile ~/.single_command_bashrc
```

(I use `konsole` and in my case it is `konsole -e bash --rcfile …`.)

Notes:

1. If `bash` gets `~/` inside the option-argument to `--rcfile`, it will expand it on its own. This means you can use the above (or similar) command even in a context where tilde expansion does not occur. I mean regardless if `~/` gets expanded before `foot` runs, or by `foot` (I totally don't know if `foot` even tries), or by our special-purpose `bash`, it should work.
2. "One command" the user will be able to execute can be almost arbitrarily complex piece of shell code: many commands separated by `;` and/or `&`, connected by `&&` and/or `||`; including pipelines, here-documents etc. This may or may not be what you want.
3. While typing a command, you are typing directly in Bash: you can have your prompt (my code expands it slightly), your key bindings, tab completions, you can use any shell syntax. There is no need to worry about `IFS`, no need for `read`, `eval` or anything, no additional level of parsing. The shell works *normally* until the next prompt is about to be printed.
4. The user can easily circumvent the mechanism. Few obvious angles of attack:

   - ```
     whatever; false
     ```
   - ```
     unset PROMPT_COMMAND
     ```

   The solution is certainly not a way to restrict the user. It's for a cooperative user.
5. Our file simply sets `PROMPT_COMMAND`. If you normally use `PROMPT_COMMAND` for something (e.g. already set it in `~/.bashrc`) then you may want to append to `PROMPT_COMMAND` rather than to overwrite it.
6. `exit` exits the shell. It's up to the terminal emulator if it closes automatically after the shell exits.
7. There are commands that encode useful information in their exit status and formal "failure" (non-zero exit status) from them does not necessarily mean something went wrong. E.g. in `echo foo | grep bar` the exit status from `grep` is `1` which means "pattern not found", it does not mean `grep` failed to do its job.